# compact if loop python

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I want to return these results with a def in Python:

```
title_case('a clash of KINGS', 'a an the of') # should return: 'A Clash of Kings'
title_case('THE WIND IN THE WILLOWS', 'The In') # should return: 'The Wind in the Willows'
title_case('the quick brown fox') # should return: 'The Quick Brown Fox'
```

the solution can be this:

```
def title_case(title, minor_words=''):
    title = title.capitalize().split()
    minor_words = minor_words.lower().split()
    return ' '.join([word if word in minor_words else word.capitalize() for word in title])
```

I can not understand the last line. What I get from this is this:
if 'word' is in 'minor_words' join the 'minor_words' ==> which is not what we want. we want to join the 'title'

the second question is about the first line of this solution. why is there =''?
I tried to write the "minor_words" with and without this and the output was the same.

Comment: `minor_words=''` is a default value. If you call the function with only one argument, the second argument defaults to an empty string.

Comment: If you leave out `=''` the third example will get an error.

Comment: It's one thing to pass a title and let the function split it into words; `minor_words` should be a list to begin with.

Comment: @Barmar so this default value insert a ' ' in minor_words before inserting anything in it and in case we don't have anything as minor_words, we won't get an error. am I right?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: @chepner can we pass a random title if it is just a name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if 'word' is in 'minor_words' join the 'minor_words'

No, that's not what it means.

`word if word in minor_words` means that if `word` is in `minor_words`, we join `word` (which is a word from `title`).

`else word.capitalize()` means that if `word` is *not* in `minor_words`, we join the capitalized word.

> why is there `=''`?

That provides a default value to the `minor_words` parameter. In the last example, where you call the function with only one argument:

```
title_case('the quick brown fox')
```

it's equivalent to:

```
title_case('the quick brown fox', '')
```

Without the default value you would get an error that not enough arguments were provided.